# Cannot see iTunes Radio on my device after updating to iOS7

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes-radio

I just have a quick question regarding the iTunes radio function. My girlfriend and I updated our iPhone 5 at the same time. She got the iTunes Radio, and mine is nowhere to be found. I open iTunes and cannot seem to find it anywhere. Anyone else experienced this?

I currently live in Norway with a Norwegian account, if that matters :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [zdnet.com](http://www.zdnet.com/itunes-11-1-ships-with-itunes-radio-genius-shuffle-podcast-stations-and-better-ios-7-sync-7000020880/) (today),

> iTunes Radio is only available to U.S. account holders at launch and is also available in iOS 7.

The article is about iTunes 11.1, but I presume the same goes for iOS 7.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITunes_Radio) (today) states:

> Currently, iTunes Radio is only available in the US.

[TechCrunch](http://techcrunch.com/2013/09/18/apple-releases-ios-7-ready-itunes-11-1-with-itunes-radio-podcast-stations-and-more-for-mac-and-pc/) (yesterday) has:

> Also remember that iTunes Radio is for U.S. iTunes account holders only for now, with no word on when international users will gain access just yet.

Comment: Thanks! So, I might assume that the fact that my girlfriend found in her phone was related to a bug or issue with the release yesterday?

Comment: @NicklasWinger I can't tell. The question didn't specify the account (US? Norwegian?) of your girlfriend.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Norwegian account and Norwegian OS :)

Comment: Must be IOS7 specific, my iTunes radio on MacBook Air (10.8.4)works in Spain, while I got the computer in Germany.

Comment: I would presume that people outside the US getting access to the service is due to failures in the software to detect properly what account or location is accessing the service. When servers strain to keep up load, perhaps they intentionally left the doors more open than they planned to avoid cutting off some US users? Time will tell, but it's clearly meant for US account holders only from the press release and documentation.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter where you are currently, what matters is that if your account registered as a US iTunes Store or not. I am here in Brasil and I have no problems using the radio here.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem before & here's the solution that I discovered:

1. Go to the App Store & search for your Apple ID at the bottom of the **Featured** section.
2. Tap your Apple ID & select **View Apple ID**.
3. Choose the **Change of Country** option, then select **US** as your country, and fill out the rest.
4. Once you are done changing the country, repeat Step 1 & 2 but select **Sign Out**.
5. Lastly, sign in again. Then check your iTunes Radio now in the Music app.

Comment: Changing the country of your account may impact gift cards which you haven't fully used yet and could have other side effects as well. So proceed with care!

Answer (score -3):

just go to itunes, change your coutry region to us. as simple as that

Answer (score -3):

This may seem silly, but it worked for me. Try turning ur phone off and on again. It will be there :)

Answer (score -4):

So when I updated my iPad yesterday I got I tunes radio but the next day it disappered then I read a post saying that if u double click ur home button and swipe all the thing away u will get it .and it works

Comment: @user59128 the way to thank someone on the Stack Exchange network is to up vote their answer.